# Does it exist a countable set such that any sequence with value in $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded by a sequence in this set?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

The question is simple, and the answer may be obvious, but it eludes me... Does it exist a countable set of sequences $S \subset \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\forall v \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}, \exists u \in S, v \leq u$$

Comment: What is your ordering $\leq$ on $\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$?

Comment: The usual ordering, $$v \leq u \Leftrightarrow \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, v_n \leq u_n $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, by a diagonalization argument. Let $S=\{s^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb N\}$, where $s^{(n)}=\left\langle s_k^{(n)}:k\in\Bbb N\right\rangle$. For each $k\in\Bbb N$ let

$$s_k=1+\max\left\{s_k^{(n)}:n\le k\right\}\;,$$

and let $s=\langle s_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$. Then for each $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $s^{(n)}\not\le s$.

Comment: Thanks ! I should have think of this... :(

Comment: @Tryss: You’re welcome! (I know that feeling all too well myself.)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a 'diagonalization' argument. Since your sequences are countable you can list them as $S_N $ for natural numbers $N $ and then construct a sequence that is greater than $S_n (N) $ for all $n$ less than or equal to $N $. Then no sequence in your set will dominate the construcTed sequence.